# Recorrer contenido TreeTableView

Tags: javafx

Tengo una `TreeTableView`con una columna que muestra una lista de deportes así:

```
-Fútbol
   -Americano
       Normal
       Intenso
   -Europeo
       Normal
       Intenso
```

Después de que el usuario modifique el orden quiero leer los ítems para guardarlos en una base.
El problema que se me presenta es que no se como acceder a cada uno de los ítems de forma consecutiva.

He probado ha hacerlo de forma recursiva:

```
private void extraerÍtems (TreeItem row){

    for (Object ítem: row.getChildren() ){
        System.out.println (((TreeItem)ítem).getValue());
        if (((TreeItem)hijo).getChildren().size()>0){
           System.out.println (((TreeItem) ítem).getChildren().size()); 
           extraerÍtems((TreeItem) ítem); 
        }
    }
```

pero no acaba de funcionar ya que quiero que me devuelva el nombre del deporte. Si lo hago así funciona:

```
for (int i = 0; i< treeTableView.getRoot().getChildren().size(); i++) {
    System.out.println ("Ítem: " + treeTableView.getRoot().getChildren()           
                        .get(i).getValue().getDeporte());
}
```

Pero de esta forma no puedo acceder al contenido de los ítems hijos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El hecho de que no puedas acceder a los diferentes valores de las columnas se debe a que pasas como parámetro a la clase `extraerÍtems` un `TreeÍtem` sin especificar el tipo de dato. Por ejemplo si tus datos están en una clase `MisDeportes` tendrías que escribir:

```
private void extraerÍtems (TreeItem<MisDeportes> row)...
```

El código completo sería algo como esto:

```
private void extraerÍtems (TreeItem<MisDeportes> row){

        for(TreeItem<ÍtemTabla> hijo: row.getChildren()){                                                
            System.out.println(hijo.getValue().getDeporte()+ ", hijo de " + hijo.getParent().getValue().getDeporte());            
            if(hijo.getValue().isParent()){                          
                extraerÍtems (hijo); 
            }
        }       
    }
```

Otro error común es definir el elemento raíz con un tipo distinto a `MisDeportes`. Si esto es así el código anterior mostrará un error quejándose que se intenta acceder a un tipo de datos distinto al que se espera.